# ActiveRecord .exists?() and default_scope weirdness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, exists, default-scope

We have a `default_scope` on our User class which restricts users to a set of companies:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope do
    c_ids = Authorization.current_company_ids
    includes(:companies).where(companies: { id: c_ids })
  end

  has_many :company_users
  has_many :companies, through: company_users
end

class CompanyUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
  validates_uniqueness_of :company_id, scope: :user_id
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_users
  has_many :users, through: company_users
end
```

Calling `User.last` or `User.find_by_email('mhayes@widgetworks.com')` or `User.find(55557)` all work and scope as expected.

Calling `User.exists?(id)` throws an odd error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'companies.id' in 'where clause': SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users`  WHERE `companies`.`id` IN (4) AND `users`.`id` = 55557 LIMIT 1
```

Basically, if I'm getting this, it's saying that `companies` isn't a column on `User`, which it is. And if I even copy the sql into a `where` statement, it evaluates correctly.

```
User.where("SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users`  WHERE `companies`.`id` IN (4) AND `users`.`id` = 66668 LIMIT 1")
```

It makes me think there's an order of evaluation with `default_scope` and `exists?` is somehow called before `default_scope`.

If I call:

```
User.includes(:companies).where(companies: { id: [4] }).exists?(55557)
```

Works. And this is what the `default_scope` is doing, so I know the `default_scope` scope isn't failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly don't know, but it looks to me like `exists?` builds a *relation* directly and decides to throw out the `includes` clause because `exists?` decides that it doesn't need to load other objects. That happens in [this method call](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c9642e31b1a9f764fbf1ce85b38fa225ec5e6b42/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L230). Whereas the *chained* `exists?` has already calculated it properly from building an earlier *relation* (where the `includes` get converted into a `joins`).

Maybe not a bug but probably another weirdness to add to the list with `default_scope`.

Probably the best solution is to make the `includes` in the `default_scope` into an actual `joins` and the manually call `includes` whenever you actually need the full records. (Since you don't actually need them for the `exists?` call)

Another possibility is just chain both `includes` and `joins` in the `default_scope`. I have no idea what this does to the `arel` calculations although I doubt much. **May or May Not Work.**

Or if you just really want it to stay the same overall, you could do something crazy like:

```
def self.exists?(args)
  self.scoped.exists?(args)
end
```

Which will basically build a *relation* with the default scope and then call `exists?` on that built *relation* that already performed the `includes` -> `joins` magic.

Comment: Yep. Chaining `includes` and `joins` in the `default_scope` works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
User.exists?(id: 55557)
```

Comment: Yes. This throws the error `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'companies.id' in 'where clause': SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users`  WHERE `companies`.`id` IN (4) AND `users`.`id` = 55557 LIMIT 1`